# function that returns True/False with a foreach loop in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell function that receives a number and creates that many users.

That function has a simple `foreach` that loops over all the numbers between 1 and the argument sent to the function.
Inside the loop there is a `try` and `catch` blocks to run the commands I need and handle error.

My question is, how can I make the function `return $true` only after all users have been created?

thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Count the number of successful iterations, and ensure they match the received number.  Do you have a [mcve] that is not working as intended?

Comment: that would mean i would have to add a counter after a successful user creation and after the for-each loop ends i would compare it to the original argument the function received? i guess that would solve the issue. thank you :)

Comment: Another option is to initialy set `$result=$true` and in your `catch`blok set `$result=$false`. Still an extra variable is needed but it's a tad simpler.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - The only issue with that is, there's no code provided in this question.  Without seeing the code, we can't guarantee that any other section could have an exception.  All users may have been created... then something else could fail, and `$false` would potentially be erroneously reported.

Comment: @gravity - true, that's for OP to consider and handle properly

Comment: PLEASE, provide a simplified bit of working code that shows what you have tried ... and what did not work as intended.

Comment: thank you for you help. both approaches worked for me. i dont have a piece of code that does not work as intended because I didnt know how to do it so I didnt have any piece of code yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
function Add-SomeStuff {
  param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)][int]$NumberOfUsers
  )
  [bool] $toReturn = $true
  foreach ($i in 1..$NumberOfUsers) {
    try {
      # In some case, your function here could return the value
      # and have an impact on toReturn's value
    }
    catch {
      $toReturn = $false
    }
  }

  return $toReturn
}
```

The value `toReturn` might be modified inside the try, if your specific code returns a boolean for example which say if the user has been successfully added or not. 
In this case, you can do something like this: 
`$toReturn = $toReturn -and $(Add-User ...)`